# How to download WFS data using ogr2ogr?

Tags: wfs, ogr2ogr

My plan is to download data from a WFS (https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_nas-konform?VERSION=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities) and to convert it to GeoJSON using ogr2ogr.

I ran

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON dummy.geojson WFS:"https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_nas-konform?VERSION=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=adv:AX_Flurstueck&BBOX=254947.56504946592,5823118.597713644,332369.2140483765,5754509.447973528,urn:adv:crs:ETRS89_UTM32"
```

but received

```
ERROR 1: No schema information loaded
ERROR 1: No schema information loaded
```

The layer I am interested in is this one

```
<wfs:FeatureType xmlns:adv="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0">
<wfs:Name>adv:AX_Flurstueck</wfs:Name>
<wfs:Title>adv_AX_Flurstueck</wfs:Title>
<wfs:DefaultCRS>urn:adv:crs:ETRS89_UTM32</wfs:DefaultCRS>
<wfs:OtherCRS>urn:adv:crs:ETRS89_Lat-Lon</wfs:OtherCRS>
<wfs:OtherCRS>urn:adv:crs:ETRS89_UTM33</wfs:OtherCRS>
<wfs:OtherCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832</wfs:OtherCRS>
<wfs:OtherCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25833</wfs:OtherCRS>
<wfs:OtherCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4258</wfs:OtherCRS>
<ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
<ows:LowerCorner>5.61272621360749 50.2373512077239</ows:LowerCorner>
<ows:UpperCorner>9.58963433710139 52.5286304537795</ows:UpperCorner>
</ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
</wfs:FeatureType>
```

but the link to the XML namespace (http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0) is dead.

What can I do?

Comment: namespace URIs don't have to resolve.

Comment: I think the issue you have is the `adv:AX_Flurstueck` featuretype is a complex feature, as shown in the DescribeFeatureType request: https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_nas-konform?VERSION=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&typename=adv:AX_Flurstueck

Answer (score 0):

If you turn debugging on (`export CPL_DEBUG='ON'`) you get the following output

```
HTTP: Fetch(https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_nas-konform?VERSION=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&BBOX=254947.56504946592,5823118.597713644,332369.2140483765,5754509.447973528,urn:adv:crs:ETRS89_UTM32)
HTTP: libcurl/7.81.0 OpenSSL/3.0.2 zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.4.8 libidn2/2.3.2 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.3.2) libssh/0.9.6/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.43.0 librtmp/2.3 OpenLDAP/2.5.14
WFS: No paging support
WFS: No ImplementsStandardJoins support
WFS: No transaction support
GDAL: GDALOpen(WFS:https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_nas-konform?VERSION=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=adv:AX_Flurstueck&BBOX=254947.56504946592,5823118.597713644,332369.2140483765,5754509.447973528,urn:adv:crs:ETRS89_UTM32, this=0x560468f8d750) succeeds as WFS.
GDAL: QuietDelete(/tmp/dummy.gpkg) invoking Delete()
GDAL: GDALDriver::Create(GPKG,/tmp/dummy.gpkg,0,0,0,Unknown,(nil))
HTTP: Fetch(https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_nas-konform?VERSION=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&TYPENAMES=adv:AX_Flurstueck&BBOX=254947.56504946592,5823118.597713644,332369.2140483765,5754509.447973528,urn:adv:crs:ETRS89_UTM32&TYPENAME=adv:AX_Flurstueck)
WFS: Turn off loading of multiple layer definitions at a single time
WFS: https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_nas-konform?VERSION=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&TYPENAMES=adv:AX_Flurstueck&BBOX=254947.56504946592,5823118.597713644,332369.2140483765,5754509.447973528,urn:adv:crs:ETRS89_UTM32&TYPENAME=adv:AX_Flurstueck
HTTP: Fetch(https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_nas-konform?VERSION=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&TYPENAMES=adv:AX_Flurstueck&BBOX=254947.56504946592,5823118.597713644,332369.2140483765,5754509.447973528,urn:adv:crs:ETRS89_UTM32&TYPENAME=adv:AX_Flurstueck)
WFS: https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_nas-konform?VERSION=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=adv:AX_Flurstueck&BBOX=254947.56504946592,5823118.597713644,332369.2140483765,5754509.447973528,urn:adv:crs:ETRS89_UTM32&COUNT=1
HTTP: Fetch(https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_nas-konform?VERSION=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=adv:AX_Flurstueck&BBOX=254947.56504946592,5823118.597713644,332369.2140483765,5754509.447973528,urn:adv:crs:ETRS89_UTM32&COUNT=1)
ERROR 1: No schema information loaded
NAS: Prescanning /vsimem/tempwfs_0x560468f85460/file.gml.
OGR: XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize()
NAS: 0 remaining classes after prescan.

GDAL: GDALOpen(/vsimem/tempwfs_0x560468f85460/file.gml, this=0x560469128470) succeeds as NAS.
NAS: Clearing classes.
OGR: XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate()
GDAL: GDALClose(/vsimem/tempwfs_0x560468f85460/file.gml, this=0x560469128470)
WFS: https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_nas-konform?VERSION=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=adv:AX_Flurstueck&BBOX=254947.56504946592,5823118.597713644,332369.2140483765,5754509.447973528,urn:adv:crs:ETRS89_UTM32
HTTP: Fetch(https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_nas-konform?VERSION=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=adv:AX_Flurstueck&BBOX=254947.56504946592,5823118.597713644,332369.2140483765,5754509.447973528,urn:adv:crs:ETRS89_UTM32)
ERROR 1: No schema information loaded
NAS: Prescanning /vsimem/tempwfs_0x560468f85460/file.gml.
OGR: XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize()
NAS: 0 remaining classes after prescan.

GDAL: GDALOpen(/vsimem/tempwfs_0x560468f85460/file.gml, this=0x5604696b24f0) succeeds as NAS.
GDALVectorTranslate: 0 features written in layer 'adv:AX_Flurstueck'
NAS: Clearing classes.
OGR: XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate()
GDAL: GDALClose(/vsimem/tempwfs_0x560468f85460/file.gml, this=0x5604696b24f0)
GDAL: GDALClose(WFS:https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_nas-konform?VERSION=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=adv:AX_Flurstueck&BBOX=254947.56504946592,5823118.597713644,332369.2140483765,5754509.447973528,urn:adv:crs:ETRS89_UTM32, this=0x560468f8d750)
GPKG: Creating insert/delete feature_count triggers
GDAL: GDALClose(/tmp/dummy.gpkg, this=0x5604692445e0)
GDAL: In GDALDestroy - unloading GDAL shared library.
```

The problem seems to be that the request for the first feature (which I suspect OGR uses to determine the schema of the features, even though it has the `describeFeatureType` result), doesn't return any features.

```
https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_nas-konform?VERSION=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=adv:AX_Flurstueck&BBOX=254947.56504946592,5823118.597713644,332369.2140483765,5754509.447973528,urn:adv:crs:ETRS89_UTM32&COUNT=1
```

which gives me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wfs:FeatureCollection timeStamp="2023-06-07T18:14:57.606+02:00" numberReturned="0" numberMatched="unknown" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0 http://www.wfs.nrw.de/aaa-suite/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/AAA-Fachschema.xsd http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://www.wfs.nrw.de/aaa-suite/schema/ogc/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 http://www.wfs.nrw.de/aaa-suite/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco http://www.wfs.nrw.de/aaa-suite/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/iso/19139/20070417/gco/gco.xsd http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd http://www.wfs.nrw.de/aaa-suite/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/iso/19139/20070417/gmd/gmd.xsd"/>
```

and hence the `ERROR 1: No schema information loaded` warning.

Interestingly adding the same server to QGis and inspecting the URLs it generates gives URLs with bounding boxes like:

```
BBOX=350341.30294873716775328,5703525.80467389803379774,350352.33451895019970834,5703536.83624411094933748,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832
```

Which do work, so I would say the problem is that your bounding box/SRS is defined wrongly (or both).

Comment: Thank you very much @Ian for the help! Could you clarify what you mean by "_SRS is defined wrongly_"? For the SRS I used the `wfs:DefaultCRS` which is `urn:adv:crs:ETRS89_UTM32` for `adv:AX_Flurstueck`. Could this be the problem? Do you know why QGIS is using `urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832`? For the coordinates of the BBOX I am actually still unsure since the order of the coordinates can (as I understand it) vary for different SRS/CRS.

Comment: You can also use the ogr2ogr parameters [-spat xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-spat_srs srs_def] for defining the bounding box just in case if GDAL knows how to convert them into a working GetFeature request. GDAL may know if QGIS can read the service.

Comment: `WFS: No paging support` might be a killer too considering number of features `numberMatched="9359426"`